# Баги с картинками, Adapter, ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, изображения, adapter

пишу новостное приложение на android, столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Думаю из видео станет понятно.

Вот, залил на Youtube...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7bJJr3skbA4

Вот код самого активити

```
public class AstActivity extends Activity {

ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
ArrayList<Product_place> products2 = new ArrayList<Product_place>();
ArrayList<Item> productsAstNews = new ArrayList<Item>();
Context ctxx;

BoxAdapter boxAdapter;
BoxAdapter2 boxAdapter2;

void fillData3() {
    loadXml();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
    startActivity(new Intent(AstActivity.this, AstActivity.class));
}

String valOfTag(String s, String tag)   // выдаёт значение тега (tag) и удаляет его из строки.
{
    String TAG_START = "<" + tag + ">";
    String TAG_END = "</" + tag + ">";

    int l = s.indexOf(TAG_START);
    int r = s.indexOf(TAG_END);

    if(r == -1 || l == -1)
    {
        return "not_found";
    }
    else
    {
        String valueOfTag = s.substring(l + TAG_START.length() + 1, r );
        return valueOfTag;
    }
}
String valOfLink(String s)
{
    String tag = "enclosure" ;
    String TAG_START = "<" + tag;
    String TAG_END = "</" + tag + ">";

    int l = s.indexOf(TAG_START);
    int r = s.indexOf(TAG_END);

    if(r == -1 || l == -1)
    {
        return "not_found";
    }
    else
    {
        String valueOfTag = s.substring(l + TAG_START.length() + 1, r );
        valueOfTag = valueOfTag.substring(valueOfTag.indexOf("url=\"") + 5, valueOfTag.length() - 3);
        //Log.d("borolis", valueOfTag);
        return valueOfTag;
    }
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ast);

    TabHost tabs = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhosts);
    ctxx = getApplicationContext();
    tabs.setup();

    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabs.newTabSpec("tag1");

    spec.setContent(R.id.tabs1);
    spec.setIndicator("О городе");
    tabs.addTab(spec);

    spec = tabs.newTabSpec("tag2");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tabs2);
    spec.setIndicator("Что посетить?");
    tabs.addTab(spec);

    spec = tabs.newTabSpec("tag3");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tabs3);
    spec.setIndicator("Новости");
    tabs.addTab(spec);

    tabs.setCurrentTab(0);

    fillData3();


private void loadXml()
{
    AsyncTask<String, Element, String> task = new AsyncTask<String, Element, String>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            String doc = "";
            try
            {
                doc = new Scanner(new URL("https://vlast.kz/feed/").openStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
            }

            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String itemx = "";
            while(itemx != "not_found")
            {
                itemx = valOfTag(doc, "item");
                if(itemx != "not_found")
                {
                    int l = doc.indexOf("<item>");
                    int r = doc.indexOf("</item>");
                    doc = doc.substring(0, l) + doc.substring(r + 7, doc.length());

                    String nameI = valOfTag(itemx, "title");    //разбираем запись на нужные нам данные
                    String linkI = valOfTag(itemx, "link");    //
                    String pubDateI = valOfTag(itemx, "pubDate");    //
                    String descriptionI = valOfTag(itemx, "description");
                    String imageLinkI = valOfLink(itemx);


                    descriptionI= descriptionI.replaceAll("(?s)\\<em\\>.*s?\\<\\/em\\>", "");
                    descriptionI= descriptionI.replaceAll("(?s)\\<i\\>.*s?\\<\\/i\\>", "");
                    nameI = nameI.replaceAll("&quot;", "");
                    descriptionI= descriptionI.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "");
                    descriptionI= descriptionI.substring(9, descriptionI.length()-4);

                    String pubDate="";
                    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
                    Date d = null;
                    try
                    {
                        d = org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils.parseDate(pubDateI);
                        pubDate = format.format(d);
                    }
                    catch (DateParseException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Item newx = new Item(nameI, imageLinkI, descriptionI, linkI, pubDate);
                    productsAstNews.add(newx);
                }
            }
            return "allDone";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String aVoid)
        {
            AdapterItem2 boxAdapter3 = new AdapterItem2(ctxx, productsAstNews);
            ListView lvMain4 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.vlastView);
            lvMain4.setAdapter(boxAdapter3);
        }
    };
    task.execute();
}
}
```

А вот Adapter

```
public class AdapterItem2 extends BaseAdapter {

Context ctx;
LayoutInflater lInflater;
ArrayList<Item> objects;

AdapterItem2(Context context, ArrayList<Item> products) {
    ctx = context;
    objects = products;
    lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

// пункт списка
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null)
    {
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.city_item, parent, false);
    }
    Item p = objects.get(position);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cityTitle)).setText(p.getTitle());
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cityDescription)).setText(p.getDescription());
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cityAdress)).setText(p.getDate());
    loadImage(p.getUrlImage(), ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cityImage)));

    return view;
}




private void loadImage(final String urlImage,final ImageView imageView)
{
    AsyncTask<String,ImageView,Bitmap> taskx = new AsyncTask<String, ImageView, Bitmap>()
    {
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            Bitmap image = null;
            try
            {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return image;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    };
    taskx.execute(urlImage);
}
}
```

Comment: Будьте добры не выкладывать столь длинные простыни кода. В вашем случае достаточно было приведение содержимого метода `getView`. Чем больше вы выкладываете кода, тем меньше человек захочет в нём разбираться.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Это происходит из-за переиспользования уже созданных `View` адаптером.

Чтобы исправить это, вы можете воспользоваться костылём убирания картинки из `ImageView` перед загрузкой её туда. Т.е. добавить

```
(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cityImage).setImageDrawable(null);
```

перед

```
loadImage(p.getUrlImage(), ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cityImage)));
```

---

И кстати, не пишите свои велосипеды для давно решённых задач типа занрузки картинок. Используйте готовые решения типа [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco) etc

Comment: хм, это ничего не изменило..

Comment: @Borolis, ну, вам ещё надо ViewHolder в адаптере реализовать, по идее. В интернете куча статей на эту тему. Это, вроде, должно решить проблему. А вообще вам надо весь этот код переписать под `RecyclerView` и библиотеку для загрузки картинок. То, что у вас сейчас - очень устаревший подход полный велосипедов)

Comment: я решил проблему немного банальнее) сначала скачал все картинки в list bitmap'ов и уже потом просто заполнял вьюшки из готового массива)

Comment: @Borolis, можно и так, и всё же повторюсь - вы используете костыли и велосипеды)

Comment: ну как сделать без них я пока не до конца понимаю)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте паттерн ViewHolder в ArrayAdapter, пример:

```
public class ViewHolder{
        private ImageView image;
    }

@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.city_item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        loadImage(p.getUrlImage(), holder.image);

        return convertView;
    }
```